# Make Gson serialize Set with certain order

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I have a map like this: `Map<String, Integer>`. The key of the map is a string which generated by serializing a `Set<String>` by Gson.

I am worried about Gson might not always serialize the same `Set<String>` to identical string (The order of items might be different?).

This will cause trouble if I have a `Set<String>` and try to update/delete corresponding entry in that map.

Assume map's key has to been a string which is a `Set<String>`serialized by Gson. I am wondering if there is a way to force Gson to always serialize the same `Set<String>` to identical String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The order in the HashSet isn't same. If you really want them to be ordered, use ArrayList and  make your own serializer.

One ugly way may be by storing Keys in one ArrayList and values in another ArrayList.

But the problem still exists!! When parsing JSON object, the fields in the JSON object will not be in order.

So you should not rely on order and use index in HashMap or JSONObject. Rather you should use keys.